# Security practices for internal web application

Tags: security

I am a developer working on an internal web-based application, and I have been given responsibility to make sure the system is secure. I have no experience in this area, but I still want to do the best job I can: I'm in the middle of reading OWASP's guide (http://surfnet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/owasp/Guide/2.0.1/OWASPGuide2.0.1.pdf), but there is a lot of information to process, and unfortunately deadlines are deadlines.

Can the knowledgeable users here at Stack Overflow please poke holes in my design and show me where my understanding is lacking? If the entire idea is fundamentally flawed, knowing that would be appreciated, too. Thanks for any input.

This application is hosted internally, and should not be visible at all externally, even though it is accessed over our wireless networks. I trust our network engineers to handle this, though.

The users of this application are only a subset of all the employees in this corporate environment. In addition, even authorized users should be limited to only the information pertaining to them (which is largely an application-level concern, but I want to make sure exploits are not possible).

### Security Framework for Internal Web Application (by a newbie)

All communication with the web server is done over HTTPS connections.

Logging in

1. User enters name and password, which are POSTed over an HTTPS connection
2. If the name and password are correct, generate a token, and store it in a cookie. Also store the cookie in the database for future lookup. The token should have an expiration date and is associated with only the user that generated it.

Requests

1. Check that the token supplied is still valid (not expired)
2. Check that the token is valid for the user making the request
3. If everything checks out, refresh the token's validity for another 30 minutes (or so)
4. Otherwise, deny access

Comment: I have edited the question to somewhat clarify who the users of this system are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds good.
The token can either be a signed expiration date (signed with a private key stored on the server) or a sequence of cryptographically secure random bytes which is stored in a database.

Unless the token is specific to an IP address, everything must be done over SSL.

---

Independently of authentication, you'll also need to look out for SQL injection, CSRF, XSS, and other security holes.

Comment: IP-address isn't enough these days... users behind the same NAT will share an IP, but can not always be assumed to be mutually trusting.

Comment: @kander: In a corporate environment, that's probably not true.

Comment: I disagree... on a corporate network there can be various groups of users, not all of which need to be authorized to access the same resources. And since we don't know anything about the hosting (internal application can very well mean intended for employees only, but hosted somewhere in a cloud environment), this is still something to keep in mind. Good to see you added other vulnerabilities, BTW.

Comment: @kander: In a corporate environment, there probably aren't any NATs.

Comment: I don't know what corporate environments you're in... but the ones I've seen so far definitely use NAT... would be pretty expensive (and pointless) to give every desktop in a corporate network its own public IP?

Comment: @kander: But there isn't (at least in my experience) a NAT between the clients and the internal server.

Answer (score 0):

Important consideration: The entire session has to be over SSL. [Firesheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep) has demonstrated quite clearly that being able to sniff cookies (by being on the same network as the victim) leaves your users open to session hijacking.

Security is more than just logging in. You'll want to read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [Cross-Site Scripting Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), on the very least (the two most common attacks against web-applications).

Comment: There will be no user-created content in this application, so with my limited knowledge, that seems to take care of XSS. In regard to SQL injection, if I purely use stored procedures without the use of dynamic queries (EXEC), does that protect me from injection?

Comment: No user-created content: Check (unless, there is some content that the users DO have influence over, even if you didn't consider it user-created content... if input from the URL or a POST-parameter is somehow included on the page, make absolutely sure to escape it.. error pages are notorious for this..). Stored procedures are an excellent tool to safeguard against SQL injections.

Comment: Good point. I will definitely keep an eye to that as the application takes shape.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks. They bypass cookie checks and company firewalls.